# Imgur gifv file doesn't load with iframe - video - img tags

Tags: javascript, backend, gif

I used `<iframe>` and `<video>` methods but still not able to load `.gifv` vis on my website. I can't change the format because I am getting these vids with API. Is there a way to load these vids successfully?

```
            <video controls class = "gifv" id = "gifv">
            <source src = "${urlpostsb[0]}" type = "video/mp4">
            </video>
```

Comment: Can you provide a demo value for `${urlpostsb[0]}` for testing purposes?

Comment: `  for (let x = 0; x < 10; x++){
    redditFetch({
      subreddit: 'wallpapers',
      sort: 'hot',
      allowNSFW: true,
      allowModPost: false,
      allowCrossPost: true,
      allowVideo: false
      }).then(post => {
          urlpostsb.push(post.url);
          headerpostsb.push(post.title);
      });
  }`

Answer (score 0):

You can create an embed from this link:

```
<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="a/RGvtS7V">
    <a href="//imgur.com/a/RGvtS7V"></a>
</blockquote>
<script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

You just have to take the code after /gallery/ and put it into the data-id and href.

https://imgur.com/gallery/ **RGvtS7V**

data-id="a/**RGvtS7V**"

href="//imgur.com/a/ **RGvtS7V**"

But when it comes to only embedding the video itself i haven't found a solution for that.

Comment: I tried it too but now it's working with your link when I am trying to give it another href link it's just giving this error "Refused to display 'https://imgur.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'."

Comment: Yes imgur doesn't allow you to embed there entire page only a widget.

Comment: Many websites block embedding because it can be used to impersonate the embedded website.